# ReSharper custom pattern ambiguous with multiple member definitions

Tags: c#, resharper

I am attempting to transform eager class instantiation to lazy instantiation.
I've followed the eager pattern throughout the codebase, but now want to change it to the lazy alternative (and remove the setter while I'm at it).  ReSharper's custom pattern find/replace seems like the perfect tool for this.

**Happy**

If I have `private....` by itself, the pattern searches fine.

If I have `public....` by itself, the pattern searches fine.

**Sad**

As soon as I try to combine the two lines, it fails with "pattern is ambiguous"

**Unknown??**

If it helps, when I have the `private...` line and paste in the second blip, the auto-placeholder mechanism fails to do anything with `$name$`.  Again, both segments work perfectly by themselves.  I'm at a loss.

[image]

Note: There is analogous behavior in the "replace" box, which is why I'm largely ignoring it in my description of the problem.

**Update 12/11/2015**

I tried this in ReSharper 10 (Ultimate) and I get the same failing behavior.

**Update 9/8/2016**

Latest test in "ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2" still fails.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the `Match similar constructs` checkbox?

Comment: @knittl No change whether it's checked on not.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-461371

Comment: For anybody finding this years later, I think VS Code's find/replace with regex should be able to do the trick.  It allows for searching/replacing across many lines and also regex substitutions.

Comment: @emragins Did you try to "Add Placeholder" and set the name value to `$name$` and the type value `Identifier`? Because your current setup could confuse ReSharper. So defining those could fix it.

Comment: @AztecCodes I think that's what my screenshots shows I tried, and yes, it's definitely confused.  In any case, this question is 7.5 years old and I'm not in a position to do tests anymore.