# Why can't resharper find this semantic pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, editor, resharper

I wish to use reshaper to replace all my INPC code by matching the pattern

```
private $type$ _$id$;
public $type$ $name$
{
    get { return _$id$; }
    set { RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _$id$, value); 
}
```

and replacing it with

```
[Reactive] 
public $type$ $name$ { get; set;}
```

but resharper warns me that the "pattern is ambiguous". I would have thought that the above semantic search and replace is exactly what the "search with pattern" tools is designed to do. Any ideas on how to make it work. I don't particularly want to try a regex to do the job.

[image]

Comment: Duplicating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210827/resharper-custom-pattern-ambiguous-with-multiple-member-definitions

Comment: Damn. It's sitting in JetBrains Youtrack. Somebody should be able to write a roslyn based system that is superior to this.

Comment: It's rather complicated :)

Comment: https://github.com/kswoll/ReactiveUI.Fody/pull/27

Comment: But yeah a general solution for semantic search and replace is probably complex. It would sure make writing code fixes easier though if somebody could nail it.